# how to protect the program from errors related to reading the frame (serial port)

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I use SerialPort to exchange information with my divice.

```
       if (cmd.BytesReceived == 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received=0");
                cmd.BuforRecv = new byte[2];
                cmd.BuforRecv[0] = (byte)cmd.Port.ReadByte();
                cmd.BuforRecv[1] = 1; //header o długości 2
                cmd.BytesReceived++;
            }
            if (cmd.BytesReceived == 1)
            {
                if (cmd.Port.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    byte h1 = cmd.BuforRecv[0];
                    byte h2 = (byte)cmd.Port.ReadByte();                        
                    cmd.BytesReceived++;
                    if (h2 >= 5)    //exception
                    {
                        cmd.BuforRecv = new byte[h2 + 1];
                        cmd.BuforRecv[0] = h1;
                        cmd.BuforRecv[1] = h2;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I used Salese Logic and check frame. It show i always get whole frame. But program sometimes didnt see it and cmd.Port.BytesToRead equals less when should 6/9.

I read very often 10times/sec. 
I tried add sleep.
Or check in loop while dont get all bytes, but sometimes i overruns time to read and it again throw exception "the port is closed". I had about 100 milisecond to read frame.

Why this happen?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. If you write " it again throw exception" please also explain what kind of exception and what this exception has told you. Post all this in your question

Comment: I forgotten, but is only "the port is closed". Because i exceeded read time.

Comment: why would the port be closed? I don't see any port closing code in your post.

Comment: Because it started configuration for my serial port serialPort.ReadTimeout;